# Output of ls -l command

Tags: linux

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker
```

command gave me this output:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  54 May  8 15:37 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
```

what does '`->`' sign means?

Comment: Welcome! It just means it's a *symlink* -> (of) *file*

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81674/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the first character `l` in the `ls -l` output that the type of the file is a symbolic link.

The file `docker` in directory `/usr/local/bin` is the actual link and `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker` is the linked file, i.e.
the real binary of Docker.

The arrow `->` is just a symbol inserted by `ls -l` for a user-friendly representation of the target of the symbolic link as in "points to" or "links to".

The reason for the symlink is that `/usr/local/bin` is most likely present in your PATH variable, thus you can call `docker` from anywhere in your shell without

- explicitly adding `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/` to your PATH or
- calling the command with an absolute (or relative) path to this directory.